# How do I change the color of my bash commands (only) in a terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I've played with [color codes](http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux) to jazz up my prompt, but is there a way to change the color of what I type after said prompt to make my commands a little more distinctive in the scrollback?

I can leave an open color code tag which sort-of works (not really); it bleeds up to the first colored bit in the output (which may or may not exist).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it can be done more cleanly than you did.
 After unsuccessfully playing with the bashrc file, I found that other users achieved this [using a DEBUG trap](http://chakra-linux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Color_Bash_Prompt#Different_colors_for_text_entry_and_console_output).
It's hacky, but it works on my setup.

Comment: http://chakra.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Different_colors_for_text_entry_and_console_output